# Join Tables with no Join Criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql

This seems so simple, but I just can't figure it out.  I want to simply join 2 tables together.  I don't care which values are paired with which.  Using TSQL, here is an example:

```
declare @tbl1 table(id int)  
declare @tbl2 table(id int)  

insert @tbl1 values(1)  
insert @tbl1 values(2)  
insert @tbl2 values(3)  
insert @tbl2 values(4)  
insert @tbl2 values(5)  

select * from @tbl1, @tbl2
```

This returns 6 rows, but what kind of query will generate this (just slap the tables side-by-side):
1       3
2       4
null 5

Comment: so you want pairs? for every row in table A, you want a row from table B?

Comment: OK, I'm curious: What for? This is seriously not your standard sql usage.

Comment: Maybe a first pass at a dating application? ;-) I can't say I've ever done this but I *could* see where it might be useful.

Comment: It would give somewhat random results (only, always the same). I think you might be on to something with this dating idea :)

Comment: Attempt to explain reason: Parent child tables. Have set of child details which need to be inserted, but some parent-children may already exist.  I add new parent rows outputting the parent id.  Now I want to do a merge against the child, when no matches found on the merge, insert new children.  Each child needs a newly added parent id, it matters not which.  Hope that kind of explains it.

Comment: I'm still puzzled about why this is outside the realm of set theory (since no existing join will produce the desired set).  It seems a valid set to me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give each table row numbers and then join on the row numbers:

```
WITH
Table1WithRowNumber as (
    select row_number() over (order by id) as RowNumber, id from Table1
),

Table2WithRowNumber as (
    select row_number() over (order by id) as RowNumber, id from Table2
)

SELECT Table1WithRowNumber.Id, Table2WithRowNumber.Id as Id2
FROM Table1WithRowNumber 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2WithRowNumber ON Table1WithRowNumber.RowNumber = Table2WithRowNumber.RowNumber
```

**Edit**: Modiifed to use FULL OUTER JOIN, so you get all rows (with nulls).

Comment: I thought about that, but what if he has multiple inserts and deletions? Then his row numbers won't match up. Lots of nulls to be expected.

Comment: I think this is what he wants, except, this will only show as many rows as there are on table A

Comment: @BlackTiger - no, that is why he used a full outer join rather than a left outer join.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it Kirk...I was off playing with unpivots before I thought of using RowNumber.  My solution is slightly shorter tho ;-)

Comment: Actually, I should say *in my specific case* right outer join works.  For the generic answer to my post, full outer join would be correct.

Answer (score 6):

Use Cross Join

```
  Select * From tableA Cross Join TableB
```

But understand you will get a row in the output for every combination of rows in TableA with every Row in TableB...

So if Table A has 8 rows, and TableB has 4 rows, you will get 32 rows of data...
If you want any less than that, you have to specify some join criteria, that will filter out the extra rows from the output

Comment: Same problem as Dave's answer, won't return how he expects.

Comment: His example query will give the same answer and he's made it clear that isn't what he wants...

Comment: @Mark, The title says "with no join criteria".  Clearly, he needs join criteria to do what he wants.  That point is what my answer is attempting to communicate.

Comment: This worked for me on SQL Server DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this will work:

```
Select A.ID, B.ID From
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID FROM Tbl2 ) A
full outer join
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, ID FROM Tbl1 ) B 
on (A.RowNumber=B.RowNumber)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL1 cross join applies here also.

```
Select * 
From tableA, TableB
```

Comment: He explicitly rejected that idea in his question. :)